# A more formal phrasing of "in the future"

Tags: phrasing

Is there a more formal or better way of phrasing "*in the future*"?

Example:

> Please refrain from using said substance in the future.

Comment: Why do you think "in the future" is informal?

Comment: "Please abstain from further use of substance X"

Comment: What @Kevin said. But although *in [the] future* isn't "informal", it's not particularly "formal" either. Whereas ***henceforth*** is definitely a "more formal" alternative.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I guess as a non-native speaker I found it to be informal through my native tongue. I see now there's nothing wrong about it, however I do like the alternative _henceforth_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the excellent suggestions by FumbleFingers (*henceforth*) and bib (*prospectively*), *hereafter* might work.

But as other commenters have observed, "in the future" is not at all informal. In fact, I would rate it as slightly more formal than the frequently heard "going forward" and "from now on"—and considerably more formal than "by-and-by."

Answer (score 2):

*In the future* is likely redundant.  You could just say,

> Please refrain from using said substance.

The only situation in which you do need to say *in the future* would be if you caught someone in the act of using the substance, but wished to grant an exception to the rule for the current infraction.  In that case, *in the future* would be a perfectly natural and formal way to express that.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't realize I made the phrase redundant in the original example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the adverb *prospectively*. The adjective form *[prospective](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/prospective#prospective)*, defined in *Oxford Dictionaries Online* as

> Likely to happen at a future date; concerned with or applying to the future:
>   *a meeting to discuss prospective changes in government legislation*

In your example

> Please prospectively refrain from using said substance.

However, it sounds beyond formal, sliding into stilted.

Answer (score 0):

**Henceforth** may work if you mean "continuously in the future", but I don't believe it will work for a specific point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

## **"Moving forward" / "Outlook"**

**Moving Forward:**

> - "How will the UN manage the Syrian refugee crisis moving forward?"
> - "Lightning vs. USB-C: Which connector will Apple move forward with?"

**Outlook:**

> - "The Bitcoin Market: The outlook of cryptocurrencies and the roles they will play in the global economy."
> - "What is the short-term outlook of gas prices?"

---

Note:

@FumbleFingers is totally right in regards to how "in the future" is neither formal or informal.